# ¿Cómo obtener el listado de archivos modificados hoy en C:?

Tags: windows10, consola

Necesito un listado con los archivos que he modificado hoy. Estoy buscando modificadores en el dir que me lo permitan pero no consigo dar con ellos.
He probado lo siguiente
C:>dir /S /TW 20-12-20
Por favor echadme una mano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He probado el siguiente comando y me devuelve un resulado que encaja con lo que espero.

dir C:*.* /s /t:c | findstr 21/12/2020 > C:\diaHoy.txt

/s    me listará también los subdirectorios

/t:c  mostrará la fecha de modificación del archivo

| findstr  añado la condición que contenga la fecha en la que se han modificado los archivos que deseo ver en el listado

Y: > C:\diaHoy.txt   me los guardará en ese archivo

Se agradecería feedback.
Gracias